# ¿Como sacar el máximo y fecha SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

¿Cómo puedo añadir la fecha con el máximo?

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT MAX (TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS) AS maximo_troughput
FROM (  SELECT FECHA_MUESTRA DIA,
       LABEL,
       DL_OUT_TH_KBPS,
       ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2)
          TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
      FROM V_GF_DATA_GW_TH_KBPS
             WHERE TRUNC(FECHA_MUESTRA) >= TO_DATE ('29-10-2018','DD-MM-YYYY')
                    AND TRUNC(FECHA_MUESTRA) <= TO_DATE ('05-11-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
      ORDER BY FECHA_MUESTRA ASC, label ASC)
```

El resultado al que quiero llegar es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agregar la columna de la fecha en que se hizo el máximo.

Comment: puede utilizar max(date) esto devolvera la maxima fecha disponible! o la mas actual! ejemplo: to_char(max(FIRST_TIME),'DD-MON-YY:HH24:MI:SS')  si quieres formatearla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes una versión moderna de Oracle, puedes traer un único registro con código SQL estándar. Sería algo como:

```
select *
  from (
        SELECT   FECHA_MUESTRA DIA
               , LABEL
               , DL_OUT_TH_KBPS
               , ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2) TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
          FROM V_GF_DATA_GW_TH_KBPS
         WHERE TRUNC (FECHA_MUESTRA) = TO_DATE ('05-11-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
       ) q1
 order by TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
 fetch first 1 row only
```

Y tendrás no solo la fecha, sino todos los campos para dicho registro (si hay varios que tienen el mismo valor *máximo*, tendrás uno de ellos (aleatorio). Puedes influenciar cual (por ejemplo la fecha mínima o máxima) agregando más columnas a la clausula `order by`.

Si no tienes un oracle moderno, puedes calcular un *número de fila* en el orden específico que te interesa en la sub consulta y luego quedarte con la fila número 1 para lograrlo, pero este código es más específico de Oracle y está totalmente fuera del estándar.

```
select *
  from (
        SELECT   FECHA_MUESTRA DIA
               , LABEL
               , DL_OUT_TH_KBPS
               , ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2) TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
               , row_number() over (order by ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2) desc) as rn
          FROM V_GF_DATA_GW_TH_KBPS
         WHERE TRUNC (FECHA_MUESTRA) = TO_DATE ('05-11-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
       ) q1
 where rn = 1
```

Comment: Amigo, edite la pregunta y como lo haria para esa consulta que edite gracias te lo agradeceria.

Comment: La respeusta sigue siendo básicamente la misma. El error de formato de fecha que es lo que veo que corregiste, pues, corrigelo también en mi respuesta, en la que copie el código que publicaste como base. Un saludo.

Comment: Amigo en la consulta que me enviaste me sale este error "SQL command not properly ended" y me da error de sintaxis en "fetch"

Comment: Entonces tu oracle no soporta esa sintaxis, utiliza la segunda opción que doy en mi respuesta. ¿qué versión de oracle utilizas?

Comment: 10.6.0.42 Toad for Oracle Xpert

Comment: probaste con la segunda opción?

Comment: Si, amigo acabo de editar el post mira la consulta que tengo como lo podria hacer?

Comment: _amigo_, este no es un servicio de escritura de sentencias SQL. Ya yo te dí un ejemplo. Si te esfuerzas en entenderlo, podrás tu mismo adaptar la sentencia que quieras para lograr el mismo resultado. Agradecería que reviertas la pregunta a la original, pues con el cambio que hiciste, dejas mi respuesta (y mi esfuerzo) totalmente en el aire.